# Как стилизировать сайдбар в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, где и как можно отредактировать стиль виджетов которые выводятся в сайдбаре?(Шрифт,высоту и т.п.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В папке с темой файл loop.php
там "спагетти", конечно, но разобраться можно

Comment: Нету такого файла.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала посмотри дополнение [FireBug для FireFox](http://samodelkin.kz/dopolnenie-firefox-dlya-kazhdogo-vebmastera-firebug.html). Это дополнение поможет работать с внешним видом (стилем)всего сайта не меняя код PHP. А затем посмотри [Основы CSS теория и практика](http://samodelkin.kz/yazyk-css-osnovy-teoriya-i-praktika.html). Соединив первое со вторым получишь качественный результат.

Answer (score -1):

Можете переопределить стили виджетов, сайдбара в файле `style.css` в корне используемой темы, например.

Как правило, у виджетов есть `id` и `class name` для которых можно писать оформление.
Пример `HTML` кода виджета:

```
<li id="wpsc_latest_products-2" class="widget widget_wpsc_latest_products">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Latest Products</h3>
  <ul class="wpsc-latest-products">
    <li class="wpsc-latest-product">
      <a href="#url1" class="wpsc-product-title">Product title 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="wpsc-latest-product">
      <a href="#url2" class="wpsc-product-title">Product title 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="wpsc-latest-product">
      <a href="#url3" class="wpsc-product-title">Product title 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

пример `CSS` кода для этого виджета в файле `style.css`:

```
/* по имени класса */
.widget.widget_wpsc_latest_products {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font: 12px/14px sans-serif;
}
/* по id */
#wpsc_latest_products-2 .widget-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #eee;
}
```